Give an example of $\prod_i (M \otimes_R N_i) \ne M \otimes_R \left(\prod_i N_i\right)$
This is an exercise proposed in my course about commutative algebra, and I thought of a solution, but I don't know if it is entirely correct.
Let $R= \mathbb{Z}$ and take the module $M = \mathbb{Q}$ and the sequence of modules $N_n = \mathbb{Z}/(2^n)$ for $n \geq 1$. Then given any $n \geq 1$, we have $M \otimes_R N_n = \mathbb{Q} \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z}/(2^n) = 0$, since we can always divide any element in $\mathbb{Q}$ by $2^n$ and multiply it on the right factor making every basic tensor $0$.
So, $\prod_{n\geq0} \left(\mathbb{Q} \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z}/(2^n)\right) = 0$.
Now we want to show that $\mathbb{Q} \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \left( \prod_{n\geq1} \mathbb{Z}/(2^n) \right) \ne 0$. This is equivalent to finding an Abelian group together with a non-zero $\mathbb{Z}$-bilinear morphism from $\mathbb{Q} \times \left( \prod_{n\geq1} \mathbb{Z}/(2^n) \right) \to H$. I had the following idea. Take for $H$ again the product $\prod_{n\geq1} \mathbb{Z}/(2^n)$. Given any $q \in \mathbb{Q}$, we may write it uniquely as $q = \sum_{n\geq0} \frac{q^n}{2^n}$. So, given a tuple $(q, (\overline{a_n})_{n \geq 1})$, we map it to $(\overline{q_n a_n})_{n \geq 1}$.
I now have some trouble proving this map is a good choice. In particular, $R$-linearity in the first component is tricky. Linearity in the second component is easy enough. It also seems well-defined.
Can anyone help out? Is this map a good choice? If so, how do I prove it? If not, what did I do wrong? Thanks in advance!

Note: there are some questions on here already about this matter, but I don't seem to find any that give a counterexample or fully work it out.

I wouldn't try to construct a bilinear map explicitly. There should be a few ways to do this, but the thing that comes to my mind is using that the map $\mathbb{Z} \to \prod_{n \geq 1} \mathbb{Z} / (2^n)$ mapping 1 to $(1, 1, 1, \ldots)$ is injective, so since tensoring with $\mathbb{Q}$ is exact (either use that $\mathbb{Q}$ is injective or that it is a localization of $\mathbb{Z}$), so the map after tensoring is still injective, but $\mathbb{Z} \otimes \mathbb{Q} \cong \mathbb{Q} \neq 0$, so the codomain, too, must be non-zero.

Thanks for your answer! Later on, we indeed proved that localizations are flat modules. However, this exercise was in particular put before the theory of flat modules. The only tensor-related theory before this was just the basic definitions and the universal property. Could you do it using only those as well?

@BenSteffan Comments should only be used to clarify the problem, not answering the problem. And you have answered the question. For more information see https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment

The example is good, the proof isn't. I assume you mean $q_n$ instead of $q^n$, and you put some restrictions on the $q_n$? But in any case this map won't be a homomorphism.
To see that the tensor product is non-zero, you need to know that in general $\mathbb{Q} \otimes A$ is the localization of $A$ at $\mathbb{Z} \setminus \{0\}$, where $A$ is any abelian group. So this tensor product is zero if and only if $A$ is a torsion group.
So it remains to observe that $\prod_n \mathbb{Z}/2^n$ is not a torsion group - which I assume you manage to prove.
